# Hash of model displaying when not desired

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am working on a sign up application for presentations in Ruby on Rails.
As such, I have created several models, including a student and admin model. I am displaying the data from these models in a table with bootstrap like this:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First name</th>
      # ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <%= @student.each do |stud| %>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row"><%= stud.Firstname %></td>
      # ...
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

My controller:

```
def list
  @student = Student.all.order(:Firstname)
end
```

The problem is that the app prints a list of all the objects in the database as a hash.

`#<Presentation id: 3, Name: "Elon Musk", Year: "6 Gc", Title: "Electric Cars", Subject: "Phsics", Mentor: "Alberto Maraffio", Room: "N364", From: "13:45", Until: "14:00", Date: "07.11.18", Free: 5, Occupied: 0, Visitors: nil, created_at: "...", updated_at: "...">, #<Presentation id: 3, # ...`

This isn't in the layouts/application.html.erb file, the only way I can make it go away is by commenting out `<%= yield %>`, which, of course, hides the rest of the page as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey guys, I am not very familiar with the [tag:ruby-on-rails] community, I am just a [tag:ruby] guy, so can you point us to a canonical duplicate target? This question *must* have been asked a hundred times already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
<%= @student.each do |stud| %>
```

should not be displaied into the page. Move to

```
<% @student.each do |stud| %>
```

Besides that, I can't understand what you want to do with this line

```
@student.each = Student.all.order(:Firstname)
```

It should probably be

```
@student = Student.order(:Firstname)
```

And note how `@students` might be a better name for this variable

Comment: Thanks very much, that fixed the problem. The .each was a typo, but thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Comment: For future reference... erb tags like this, `<%= %>` will display the output of the tag

Answer (score 2):

```
def list
  @student.each = Student.all.order(:Firstname)
end
```

This looks strange for me!

It should be something like:

```
def list
  @students = Student.order(:Firstname)
end
```

Then your HTML should also be like:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First name</th>
      # ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @students.each do |stud| %>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row"><%= stud.Firstname %></td>
      # ...
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```